# National Flood Insurance Data

Tags: government, weather

I'm looking for any data on the National Flood Insurance Program. I've already found a bit but I'm curious if I'm missing anything. Here's what I have:

FEMA Flood Risk Rate Maps- https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/national-flood-hazard-layer-nfhl

Loss statistics/policy information from http://bsa.nfipstat.fema.gov/reports/reports.html

The link above has a variety of reports but only the most current are posted when I asked FEMA for access to historic records I was told to file a FOIA which I did but if the records are archived anywhere online (I've already downloaded everything on the Internet Archive's site) I would be very interested.

Thanks!